# Linux commands, what do they mean?

Tags: linux, command

I am just getting started with Linux, could someone please explain these commands? (ls), (ls -l), (whoami), (pwd), (cal 2013)  and (man cal). Thanks.

Comment: `man <command>` gets a description of every single command. So if you for example do `man ls` you will see it says "list directory contents" and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man` is the very first command a Unix/Linux beginner needs to know. It means *manual* and gives access to the reference manual (or online help) of the command specified on the same line:

```
man cal
```

displays the manual of the `cal` command.

From there, you can type

```
man intro
```

to get a list with a short summary of all available commands.

Sometimes, instead of the manual of the command you requested, you'll get the manual of `bash`, which is the program that interprets all the commands you type. This means that your requested command is not a simple command like `cal` but a special command directly implemented in the bash itself. In that case, the description of your requested command is buried in the huge manual of bash.

Answer (score 2):

The only command you have to know, is "man". Type "man ls", and you'll get an answer about what "ls" does, and so on.